# How to search for a file in war,ear and jar files recursively in Linux

Tags: linux, file-search, jar

I need to search for a file (logo.png), in a folder that contains war, ear, and jar archive files.  Can anyone help me with the command?

Comment: Use this command in terminal ------> find [PATH] -name "[FILENAME]"

Comment: You mean finding files inside war, ear or jar archive file?

Comment: @kenorb yes exactly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching inside *jar* files:

```
find . -name \*.jar -exec sh -c 'printf "\n\nFile: {}"; jar tf {}' ";" | less +/foo
```

And similar with *war* files:

```
find . -name \*.war -exec sh -c 'printf "\n\nFile: {}"; unzip -l {}' ";" | less +/foo
```

Change `foo` with text of your interest (such as `abc.png`).

You can press:

- <kbd>n</kbd> to search for the next pattern match.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to search backwards,
- <kbd>/</kbd> + type `something` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to search for another phrase.

See similar, but on Windows: [Finding which jars contain a file](https://superuser.com/q/285793/87805)

Comment: if i need to search abc.png file in a war archive how can i do with the above command.

Comment: @ashok_p Replace `Foo` with `abc.png`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unzip command for this purpose:

```
unzip -t example.war |grep filename
```

Answer (score 0):

jar tvf foo.war | grep filename

Comment: While this bit of code may be correct, the lack of ANY contextualizing information makes this answer useless and unhelpful.